# Allocating memory to an array in a struct

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

I have defined a struct as below

```
struct Invariant
{
    int *           numberOfConstPi;        //  Saves the number of constant Pi in each kernel


    Invariant *     next;
};
```

I then modified it later in the code as

```
invariant->numberOfConstPi = (int *)calloc(invariant->numberOfUniqueKernels, sizeof(int));
invariant->numberOfConstPi[countKernel] = numberOfConstPi;
```

Where countKernel is an iterator and numberOfConstPi is a variable.

Is this the correct way? When I run the code I'm getting segmentation errors.

But when I instead defined the array as

```
int * hello = (int *)calloc(invariant->numberOfUniqueKernels, sizeof(int));
```

and

```
hello[countKernel] = numberOfConstPi;
```

It works perfectly fine.

Kindly ignore the int variable numerOfUniqueKernels. It's just a number which I deleted from the Struct(to make the struct look simpler for the question)

Comment: You don't show enough code to really know. Also, you need to check the return value of `calloc` to ensure that it's not `NULL`. Also, [don't cast the return value of the allocation functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/5567382).

Comment: Its a part of a compiler and hence there is a lot of code

Answer (score 4):

You don't show much code, but as for your question regarding this piece of code,

```
invariant->numberOfConstPi = (int *)calloc(invariant->numberOfUniqueKernels, sizeof(int));
invariant->numberOfConstPi[countKernel] = numberOfConstPi;
```

> Is this the correct way?

I can say, this is a valid way to do it. 
But you don't show much code and you say that you are running into segfault errors. I would guess that maybe you are not allocating memory for the pointer to struct?

You should have something like,

```
Invariant *invariant = malloc(sizeof*invariant);
```